# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que mi código se detenga si cumple con una condición?

Tags: javascript, array, bucles, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

disculpen tengo este código, la intención es que me detecte si hay alguna celda en blanco y si la hay que me muestre una alerta, esto ya lo conseguí, pero em, gustaría saber como puedo hacer para que en caso de que exista una celda en blanco no se agreguen los datos a mi hoja2, es decir que se interrumpa el resto el código

```
function Guardar(){
  var hojaActiva = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var registro = hojaActiva.getSheetByName("HOJA1");//Nombre de hoja del formulario
  var bd = hojaActiva.getSheetByName("HOJA2");//Nombre de hoja donde se almacenan los datos
   const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("HOJA1");
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const rgl = sh.getRangeList(["c16","j13","f14","c4","c6","c8","c10","c12","c14","f4","f6","f8","f10","f12"]);
  rgl.getRanges().forEach(r => {
     if(r.isBlank()){
      ui.alert(`${r.getA1Notation()} se encuentra vacía`)}
  });

  //Celdas de donde se obtendrán los datos a guardar
  var valores = [[registro.getRange("c16").getValue(),
                  registro.getRange("j13").getValue(),
                  registro.getRange("f14").getValue(),
                  registro.getRange("c4").getValue(),
                  registro.getRange("c6").getValue(),
                  registro.getRange("c8").getValue(),
                  registro.getRange("c10").getValue(),
                  registro.getRange("c12").getValue(),
                  registro.getRange("c14").getValue(),
                  registro.getRange("f4").getValue(),
                  registro.getRange("f6").getValue(),
                  registro.getRange("f8").getValue(),
                  registro.getRange("f10").getValue(),
                  registro.getRange("f12").getValue(),
                  registro.getRange("f16").getValue(),]];
//Inyección de datos a base de datos
bd.getRange(bd.getLastRow()+1,1,1,15).setValues(valores); 
 

 
}
```

Comment: ¿Quieres que se detenga tu aplicación o que se detenga la función?

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar la sentencia *throw* para terminar la ejecución de código.

```javascript
if(1 < 2) {
    throw "Código completado";
} 
console.log("No se mostrará este mensaje en consola");
```

Answer (score 0):

Una opción simple es el uso de sentencia `throw` para mostrar un error

```
  rgl.getRanges().forEach(r => {
     if(r.isBlank()){
      throw new Error(`${r.getA1Notation()} se encuentra vacía`)
  });
```

Si ejecutas la función mediante desde la interfaz de Google Sheets, por ejemplo mediante un menú personalizado, la interfaz mostrará una barra de color rojo con el mensaje. Esto podría ser mejor que usar alerta porque esta no detiene la ejecución del script y si el usuario tarda en descartarla podrías tener un error por exceder el tiempo de ejecución (6 minutos para cuentas gratuitas, 30 minutos para cuentas de Google Workspace).

En cualquier caso los registros de ejecución mostrarán el mensaje como un error.

Otra opción simple podría ser el uso de `Array.prototype.some` o `Array.prototype.every` en lugar the `Array.prototype.forEach`, para usar su resultado como condición de un `if`, pero habría que repensar lo de la notificación de cuál celda está vacía. Esto no sería problema si usas formato condicional, por ejemplo, para mostrar con fondo de color las celdas vacías.

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes hacer con la sentencia:

```
return 0;
```

De ese modo se sale de la función devolviendo el valor 0.

Comment: Estás en el sitio de Stack Overflow en español, las publicaciones en este sitio deben estar en el idioma español. Completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio y su funcionamiento general.